# Ignoring the response in java class for a http request making from class

Tags: java, httpwebrequest

Any idea how to make a  http call from java class ignoring the response .
I am trying to give a trigger/ack by hitting the URL from my java class . but i am not interested if I get the response back or not and want to continue my code flow without waiting for the response.

Comment: maybe using sockets would be better for your requirements

Comment: @stefanbachert i am not sure about how to use a Socket, but the application i am trying is Web application and the trigger which i specified is a URL hit to a third party where i dont have any access. I believe Sockets are not an option in this case. Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the input stream (response stream)

However, your approach is not reliable.
You could not even guaranty that the trigger has been done.